# how can I calculate the mean and variance of random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

There are two dependent (correlated) random variables with Rice (Rician) distributions $R_1\sim (u_1,s_1)$ and $R_2\sim(u_2,s_2)$. Then, how can I calculate the mean and variance of random variable $R$, $R$ is a ratio of the two dependent variables, i.e., $R=R_2/R_1$?

Comment: Without knowledge of the _joint_ distribution of $R_1$ and $R_2$, it is difficult to say much. Just the fact that $R_1$ and $R_2$ are dependent, or correlated with known correlation coefficient is not sufficient.

Comment: Is it possible that where you wrote $u$ you meant $\mu$?

Comment: @MichaelHardy u1 and u2 are nonzero mean.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Can you please have a look at my another question (More detailed)? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322238/the-mean-and-variance-of-the-random-variable-with-rician-distribution